# How to mock a no response from server with Gin Golang

Tags: rest, go, mocking, go-gin

I'm mocking a server for testing my application. I built the mocked server with Golang and Gin. It works well for successful cases.

But one of the cases I want to test is how the application behaves when there is no response from the server. I want that when the application sends a request with a specific value, the mocked server shall not answer. But I did not manage to achieve that with Gin.

I tried that the Gin handler function shall not set the context, but Gin still sends an empty 200 OK. A  router.GET without handler also replies with an empty 200OK. I checked the extensive Gin documentation, but I could not find an answer.

How can I simulate a server or network error where the response is never received?

Answer (score 0):

When a server returns nothing, there are two situations (that I know of)

1. The connection is open, but no response has been returned -- A Timeout
2. The connection closes, or is reset by the server -- A Network Error or Connection Reset

From the question it sounds like we're looking to model #2.

For testing purposes, a way to simulate a connection reset is by returning an error from the `http.RoundTripper` internal to the `http.Client` used in the test. Note that this doesn't involve Gin. The test is to see how some client reacts to a connection reset by the server.

Internal to an `http.Client` is an `http.RoundTripper` which is an interface which requires the method:

`RoundTrip(*Request) (*Response, error)`

According to the docs:

```
RoundTrip must return err == nil if it obtained
a response, regardless of the response's HTTP status code.
A non-nil err should be reserved for failure to obtain a
response.
```

Here's an example of how to do this:

```
type connectionResetTransport struct {}

func (c *connectionResetTransport) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    return nil, errors.New("connection reset")
}

// usage
connectionResetClient := http.Client{
    Transport: &connectionResetTransport{},
}

connectionResetClient.Get("http://localhost:8080")
// or use connectionResetClient as the http.Client in whatever system you're trying to test
```